# Match Regex Pattern which does not only consist of certain characters

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-look-ahead

I'm trying to match Strings up to a certain size which do not only consist of certain characters.

So for the first part it's rather easy. To match this:
Yes: "abcde / asbas"
Yes: "abcde/      asbas"
Yes: "abcde/    ///"
Yes: "    ///aasd"
Yes: "///  aasd"
Yes: "avcdesc"
No: "AVASD/ASDB"
I use this expression:

```
[ \/a-z0-9]{1,20}
```

But this would also match something like this: `"    ////"`
As I want to avoid this I tried to add another expression and combine them using Lookahead:

```
(?=(?![ \/]+$))(?=[ \/a-z0-9]{1,20}).*$
```

This works regarding avoiding the previous example `"    ////"`
But somehow everything character after valid characters is ignored, so the following behavior occurs:
A String like this `"asdad988AAA"` is matched.
As explained, this is not intended. Maybe someone has an idea on how to solve this.
Thanks.
Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/nmSMMu/1

Comment: You probably can use `^(?=.{1,20}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:[\/ ]+[a-z0-9]+)*$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6SuXFe/1).

Comment: First of all thanks! But strings leading with " /" or trailing with " /" or any mixture of it should be matched as well. I added some other examples: https://regex101.com/r/WQIGfm/1

Comment: So, you want `^(?=[ \/]*[a-z0-9])[a-z0-9\/ ]{1,20}$`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/WQIGfm/2). At least one lowercase letter or digit.

Comment: Can you explain the rules of what you actually want to match and what not a bit better? So far I think it is something like "only lowercase letters, no digits, space is ok but only one a time, / is ok but only once and only between either two spaces or two letters.
Looks a bit confusing to me - do you have a better description?

Comment: Ah yes sorry. So "only lowercase letters, digits, space or /, but not only space and /".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?=[ \/]*[a-z0-9])[a-z0-9\/ ]{1,20}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WQIGfm/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[ \/]*[a-z0-9])` - there must be a lowercase ASCII letter or digit after any zero or more spaces or `/` chars
- `[a-z0-9\/ ]{1,20}` - one to twenty lowercase ASCII letters, digits, `/` or spaces
- `$` - end of string.